# Ionic 2 - Error : No provider for Native Storage

Tags: ionic2

I am using Native Storage plugin as specified in the [Ionic documentation](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/native-storage/) however when I deploy on the device or emulator I get a white screen. When I inspected further after connecting it to chrome > Remote Devices > Inspect. In the console I get this error  **ERROR Error: No provider for NativeStorage!**

Any pointers ?. Please help

below is my error log:

```
NativeStorage!
    at Error (native)
    at injectionError (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:1509:86)
    at noProviderError (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:1547:12)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._throwOrNull (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3048:19)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKeyDefault (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3087:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_._getByKey (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3019:25)
    at ReflectiveInjector_.get (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:2888:21)
    at NgModuleInjector.get (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:3835:52)
    at resolveDep (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:11202:45)
    at createClass (file:///android_asset/www/build/main.js:11071:32)View_MyApp_Host_0 @ ng:///AppModule/MyApp_Host.ngfactory.js:6
```

This my version info:

```
cordova CLI: 6.5.0
Ionic Framework Version: 3.2.1
Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1
Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.7
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: Not installed
OS: Windows 10
Node Version: v6.10.0
Xcode version: Not installed
```

Package.JSON

```
 {
  "name": "cccccccc",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "clean": "ionic-app-scripts clean",
    "build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "lint": "ionic-app-scripts lint",
    "ionic:build": "ionic-app-scripts build",
    "ionic:serve": "ionic-app-scripts serve"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/http": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "4.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "4.1.0",
    "@ionic-native/core": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/facebook": "^3.10.2",
    "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.10.3",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "3.7.0",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.0.1",
    "cordova-android": "^6.2.3",
    "cordova-plugin-console": "^1.0.5",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^1.1.4",
    "cordova-plugin-facebook4": "^1.9.0",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^4.0.3",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.2.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-nativestorage":"^2.2.2",
    "ionic-angular": "3.2.1",
    "ionic-native": "^2.5.1",
    "ionic-plugin-keyboard": "^2.2.1",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.1.1",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "1.3.7",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova": "1.1.2",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "1.1.2",
    "typescript": "2.2.1"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-console": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "ionic-plugin-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-facebook4": {
        "APP_ID": "3xxxxxxxxxx2",
        "APP_NAME": "cxxxxxxe"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Have you set it as provider in app.module.ts?

Comment: yes, i have added it as a provider

Comment: can you add package.json?

Comment: I didn't get you..do you mean is it added in package.json?. It is added as a dependencies   "@ionic-native/native-storage": "^3.10.3",

Comment: I meant can you include your package.json to the question

Comment: change port of server like this `ionic serve --port 8101` and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all thank you for all the responses, @Suraj I checked the package.json after you mentioned it, there I had to manually add  `"cordova-plugin-nativestorage":"^2.2.2",` under dependencies And then did clean and build. Now it works fine on Device and on Emulator. A big thank you for bringing that up!!

Answer (score 7):

Did this ?

1) Import Your nativestorage plugins to your apps.module.ts :

```
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage';
```

2) set Provider as :

```
providers: [
  NativeStorage ,
  {provide: }
  ]
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I did those, like I said I followed up the documentation. And still have the issue

Comment: @Arun-getting same error while running in device also?

Comment: In an actual device I am not able to see the error, it only displays a white screen. When i use the emulator, I still see the white screen, but then i can debug using chrome.

Comment: Actually, this is wrong, accordign to the ionic native plugin installation guidelines you need to add /ngx in you import in the app.module : import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';

Answer (score 2):

1. import *NativeStorage* in your working module as follows:

`import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';`

2. add it to **providers** like this:

   `providers: [NativeStorage]`

**full example**: `services.module.ts`

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { NativeStorage } from '@ionic-native/native-storage/ngx';
import { NativeStorageService } from './native-storage/native-storage.service';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  providers: [NativeStorage, NativeStorageService] 
})
export class ServicesModule { }
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the entry:

```
 "ionic-native": "^2.5.1",
```

as it is the older ionic-native that is not required for ionic-native 3.x

Also try to use `@ionic-native/native-storage` version same as that of `@ionic-native/core`.

```
"@ionic-native/native-storage": "3.7.0"
```